# How do I use scanf() to take an arbitrary amount of integers?

Tags: c

The program takes an arbitrary amount of integers as an input and gives an output of that integer and that amount of stars.

E.g.

```
In: 1 2 3
Out: 
1 | *
2 | **
3 | ***
```

Another example:

```
In: 2 5 6 8
Out:
2 | **
5 | *****
6 | ******
8 | ********
```

How do I do it??

Btw, amateur C programmer

And how do I add a single line space "\n" between lines in Stack Overflow question format

Comment: use <br> tag at the end of Line for "\n"

Comment: You should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764014/how-do-you-read-scanf-until-eof-in-c (reading until End Of File)

Comment: if you want to be a great programmer you have to read books and use search!

Comment: Read the input, tokenize it, parse it, and print. It should be possible with `fgets` and `strtoul`.

Comment: I am two weeks into C so, I am quite noob!

Answer (score 4):

for reading numbers from a line, you can :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char buffer[1000];
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0){
        int i,j,a;
        for(i=0; sscanf(buffer+i,"%d%n",&a,&j)!=EOF; i+=j){
            while(a-->0){
                printf("*");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never use `gets()`; it's inherently unsafe and has been removed from the language.

Comment: oops...now changed to fgets.. XD ... my apology

Comment: +1 for the proper use of the `-->` operator.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have a loop for this manner.
While user has not entered **"\n"** your program should be able to consider them as integers. Of course you can add some other checks as well.

Something like this:

```
int number = 0;
char c = '';
while(c != '\n'){
    getch(c);
    scanf("%d", &number);
    /*Do your star thing or add this number to an array for the later consideration*/
}
```

This is not fully tested and you might have to have some changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 8

int input_numbers(int numbers[]){
    int i=0,read_count;
    char ch;

    printf("In: ");
    while(EOF!=(read_count=scanf("%d%c", &numbers[i], &ch))){
        if(read_count==2)
            ++i;
        if(i==SIZE){
            fprintf(stderr, "Numeric number has reached the Max load.\n");
            return i;
        }
        if(ch == '\n')
            break;
    }
    return i;
}

void output_numbers(int numbers[], int size){
    int i,j;
    printf("Out:\n");
    for(i=0;i<size;++i){
        printf("%d | ", numbers[i]);
        for(j=0;j<numbers[i];++j){
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void){
    int numbers[SIZE];
    int n;

    n=input_numbers(numbers);
    output_numbers(numbers, n);
    return 0;
}
```