# why does NULL condition terminate after 3 chars

Tags: c

I wrote this function which is supposed to read a string into an array up to the NULL char which represents the end of the string in the line. But it somehow doesn't quite work.

```
int main(void){
    int MAX = 39;
    char number1[MAX + 1];
    int i;

    read_array(number1, MAX);

    for(i = 0; i <= MAX; i++)
        printf("%c", number1[i]);

    return 0;
}

int read_array(char* number, int size) {
    printf("\nEnter an integer number at a maximum of 39 digits please.\n");

    int result = 0;
    char* i;
    for (i = number; *i != NULL; i++)
        scanf("%c", i);

    return result;
}
```

No matter how many chars I type, as I print the result it just gives me the first 3 chars and I don't understand why. Any idea? THX

Comment: The null terminating character is `'\0'`, not `NULL` (which is the value of a null pointer). They just so happen to both equal zero, though.

Comment: tried '\0' too with the same result..

Comment: `'\0'` vs `NULL` isn't your problem; I was just correcting a misnomer. Your problem is that `scanf` doesn't insert the null terminating character, so your check isn't going to work. When the user is done entering the number, do you want them to hit enter/return? If so, check for that character, not `'\0'`. If you want to read stdin until EOF, [you can do that too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764014/how-do-you-read-scanf-until-eof-in-c).

Comment: Also, you should include more information. For example, you say "it just gives me 3 chars" but you don't say what input you're giving it. Try stepping through it with a debugger.

Comment: I thought a string is terminated by the '\0' char. thats why im checking for that.
(I edited my post for more info)

Comment: A proper C-string is terminated by `'\0'`, but this is C, you can do whatever you want. As it currently is, `number`, `number1`, and `i` are *not* strings. They are just pointers to `char`. A "string" is a higher level concept than these data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said earlier, `scanf` doesn't null-terminate your strings for you. If you want to read until the user hits enter/return, check for that. You can do that by replacing your for-loop with this do-while-loop:

```
do {
    scanf("%c", i); // read the data into i *before* the loop condition check
} while (*i++ != '\n'); // check for '\n' (unless you expect the user to
                        // actually type the null character)
```

@NedStark point about `i` pointing to junk memory is correct. The data in `number1` is never initialized, so it's just filled with junk. Your loop condition (`*i != NULL`) is checked *before* the `scanf` call, which means the loop condition is just checking old, junk data (and not the correct value).

Comment: makes sense to me but my program crashes when I try it

Comment: @ChrisBo: Then you're doing something else that you haven't posted, because I'm running this code in my debugger and it works just fine. Time to learn to use your debugger.

Comment: Ur right. My bad. Actually Im just using tcc. Got no debugger. Works now: Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your loop

```
for (i = number; *i != NULL; i++)
    scanf("%c", i);
```

After incrementing i, i points to the next memory location which contains garbage data because it 
hasn't been properly initialized. Probably you want to something like:

```
char c;
i = number;
do
{
    scanf("%c", &c);
    *i = c;
    ++i;
} while (c!='\n')
*i = '\0';
```

Comment: if I change my condition to `i < number + MAX` it works fine but then it just wont stop reading before reaching 39 chars

Comment: ur loop doesnt terminate at all btw