# C file pointer changing after fork and (failed) exec

Tags: c, linux, file, fork, stdio

I made program which make fork and I think child does not affect parent.

But file pointer is changed although I did not made any changes in the parent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("sm.c", "r");
    char buf[1000];
    char *args[] = {"invailid_command", NULL};

    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp);
    printf("I'm one %d %ld\n", getpid(), ftell(fp));
    if (fork() == 0) {
        execvp(args[0], args);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    wait(NULL);
    printf("I'm two %d %ld\n", getpid(), ftell(fp));
}
```

This outputs

```
I'm one 21500 20
I'm two 21500 -1
```

And I want to make file pointer not change between two `printf` calls.

Why does the file pointer change and can I make the file pointer unchangeable even though `execvp` fails?

Comment: Hm. Are you actually trying to execute "`invalid_command`"?

Comment: Yes. command is not available so It returns errono "No such file or directory"

Comment: You should have a look at errno, since a -1 return from ftell means an error.

Comment: There is no such an error for `ftell`... https://linux.die.net/man/3/ftell

Comment: You can test with this! thanks for your opinion

Comment: What if you put a legal command there?

Comment: I'm one 23236 20
a    ishrc    ishrc_parse.c  out      sampleish  sm.c
ish  ishrc.c  ishrc_parse.h  out_err  sm
I'm two 23236 20

Comment: You can also try removing the `execvp()` call entirely.

Comment: When I put {"ls", NULL} instead

Comment: Something fishy. Can't test it, but as far as I can tell, it should not behave this way. What `perror` would print in the end?

Comment: invailid_command: No such file or directory When I print perror(args[0]); before exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

Comment: No, not before, but after the failing `ftell`.

Comment: Run your process under [`strace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html):  `strace -f -o /path/to/output/file ...`  Post the entire output as code into the question.  It almost looks like your call to `fork()` is actually using `vfork()`, where both processes share the same address space after the call and before any subsequent `exec*()` function call in the child.  What exact version of Linux are you running on?

Comment: "Invalid argument" after last printf. I think unexpected execvp close all stream.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 with gcc compiler. I will do it! thanks

Comment: I think there's a decent chance you're running into the issue discussed/diagnosed in [Why does forking my process cause the file to be read indefinitely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50110992/), or a variant of that.  See also the linked question (from that other question — the link is to [Uwanted child processes being created while file reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244579)).

Comment: Your program does not reproduce the issue you describe for me (CentOS 7, GCC 4.8.5).

Comment: Program does not reproduce the issue on [onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/rJNlGuHWX) (only changed `"sm.c"` to `"/bin/bash"`).

Comment: Try using `_exit` in the child instead of `exit`.  That fixed it for me (Ubuntu 16.04, gcc 5.4.0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Credit to Jonathan Leffler for pointing us in the right direction.

Although your program does not produce the same unexpected behavior for me on CentOS 7 / GCC 4.8.5 / GLIBC 2.17, it is plausible that you observe different behavior.  Your program's behavior is in fact *undefined* according to POSIX (on which you rely for `fork`).  Here are some excerpts from [the relevant section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05_01) (emphasis added):

> An open file description may be accessed through a file descriptor,
>   which is created using functions such as `open()` or `pipe()`, or through
>   a stream, which is created using functions such as `fopen()` or `popen()`.
>   Either a file descriptor or a stream is called a "handle" on the open
>   file description to which it refers; an open file description may have
>   several handles.
>
> [...]
>
> The result of function calls involving any one handle (the "active
>   handle") is defined elsewhere in this volume of POSIX.1-2017, but if
>   two or more handles are used, and any one of them is a stream, the
>   application shall ensure that their actions are coordinated as
>   described below. **If this is not done, the result is undefined**.
>
> [...]
>
> For a handle to become the active handle, the application shall ensure
>   that the actions below are performed between the last use of the
>   handle (the current active handle) and the first use of the second
>   handle (the future active handle). The second handle then becomes the
>   active handle. [...]
>
> The handles need not be in the same process for these rules to apply.
>
> Note that after a `fork()`, two handles exist where one existed before.
>   The application shall ensure that, if both handles can ever be
>   accessed, they are both in a state where the other could become the
>   active handle first. [Where subject to the preceding qualification, the] application shall prepare for a `fork()`
>   exactly as if it were a change of active handle. (**If the only action
>   performed by one of the processes is one of the exec functions or
>   `_exit()` (not `exit()`), the handle is never accessed in that process.**)
>
> For the first handle, the first applicable condition below applies.
>   [An impressively long list of alternatives that do not apply to the OP's situation ...]
>
> - If the stream is open with a mode that allows reading and the underlying open file description refers to a device that is capable of
>     seeking, the application shall either perform an `fflush()`, or the
>     stream shall be closed.
>
> For the second handle:
>
> - If any previous active handle has been used by a function that explicitly changed the file offset, except as required above for the
>     first handle, the application shall perform an `lseek()` or `fseek()` (as
>     appropriate to the type of handle) to an appropriate location.

Thus, for the OP's program to access the same stream in both parent and child, POSIX demands that the parent `fflush()` `stdin` before forking, and that the child `fseek()` it after starting.  Then, after waiting for the child to terminate, the parent must `fseek()` the stream.  Given that we know the child's exec will fail, however, the requirement for all the flushing and seeking can be avoided by having the child use `_exit()` (which does not access the stream) instead of `exit()`.

Complying with POSIX's provisions yields the following:

> When these rules are followed, regardless of the sequence of handles
>   used, implementations shall ensure that an application, even one
>   consisting of several processes, shall yield correct results: no data
>   shall be lost or duplicated when writing, and all data shall be
>   written in order, except as requested by seeks.

It is worth noting, however, that

> It is
>   implementation-defined whether, and under what conditions, all input
>   is seen exactly once.

---

I appreciate that it may be somewhat unsatisfying to hear merely that your expectations for program behavior are not justified by the relevant standards, but that's really all there is.  The parent and child processes do have some relevant shared data in the form of a common open file description (with which they have separate handles associated), and that seems likely to be the *vehicle* for the unexpected (and undefined) behavior, but there's no basis for predicting the specific behavior you see, nor the different behavior I see for the same program.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to reproduce this on Ubuntu 16.04 with gcc 5.4.0.  The culprit here is `exit` in conjunction with the way the child process is being created.

The man page for `exit` states the following:

> The exit() function causes normal process termination and the value
>   of status & 0377 is returned to the parent (see wait(2)).
>
> All  functions  registered  with  atexit(3)  and on_exit(3) are
>   called, in the reverse order of their registration.  (It is possible
>   for one of    these functions to use atexit(3) or on_exit(3) to
>   register an additional function to be executed during exit processing;
>   the  new  registration    is  added to the front of the list of
>   functions that remain to be called.)  If one of these functions does
>   not return (e.g., it calls _exit(2),    or kills itself with a
>   signal), then none of the remaining functions is called,  and  further
>   exit  processing  (in  particular,  flushing  of    stdio(3)  streams)
>   is  abandoned.   If  a function has been registered multiple times
>   using atexit(3) or on_exit(3), then it is called as many    times as
>   it was registered.
>
> **All open stdio(3) streams are flushed and closed.  Files created by
>   tmpfile(3) are removed.**
>
> The C standard specifies two constants, EXIT_SUCCESS and
>   EXIT_FAILURE, that may be passed to exit() to indicate successful or
>   unsuccessful termination, respectively.

So when you call `exit` in the child it closes the `FILE` represented by `fp`.

Normally when a child process is created, it gets a copy of the parent's file descriptors.  However, in this case it seems the child's memory still physically points to the parent's.  So when `exit` closes the `FILE` it is affecting the parent.

If you change the child to instead call `_exit`, it closes the child's file descriptor but manages to not touch the `FILE` object and the second call to `ftell` in the parent will succeed.  It's good practice to use `_exit` in a non-exec'ed child anyway because it prevents `atexit` handlers from being called in the child.

Comment: I'm not buying it.  No action by one process can directly affect the memory of another, no matter the relationship between the two (or if it does then the implementation is non-conforming).  But @JonathanLeffler did seem to be onto something that explains why changing from `exit()` to `_exit()` could make a difference.

Comment: *However, in this case it seems the child's memory still physically points to the parent's. So when exit closes the FILE it is affecting the parent.* I'd think it's the calls such as `lseek()` on the underlying file descriptor in the child process as part flushing buffers on `exit()` that are affecting the offset of the parent's file descriptor.  That's certainly a much less consequential bug than cross-process memory pollution. I haven't read all the data @JonathanLeffler linked, but his theory seems a lot more likely to me.

Comment: I have to call fclose before exit and this makes my program run proper! Thanks for your answer.