# Linux x86-64 fork syscall strange behavior against C standard libc FILE I/O (keywords: fork, fclose, linux)

Tags: c, linux, fork, x86-64, stdio

### Story

I tried to diagnose a bug in an app written in C on Linux. It turned out that the bug was caused by **forgetting** `fclose` in the child process when the `FILE *` handle is still open in the parent process.

The file operation is only `read`. No write operation.

#### Case 1

The app is running on `Linux 5.4.0-58-generic`. In this case the bug occured.

#### Case 2

The app is running on `Linux 5.10.0-051000-generic`. In this case there is **no bug**, and this is what I expected.

#### What is the bug?

The parent process do random number of `fork` syscall if there is no `fclose` in child process.

#### Case 2 affirmation

I am fully aware that **forgetting** `fclose` will lead to memory leak, but:

- I think, **just in this case**, it is not strictly necessary, because the child process is going to exit as soon as possible, and the exit I use is `exit(3)` not `_exit(2)`.
- The strange thing is that, how come **forgetting** `fclose` in child process affects the parent process?

#### My current guess:

This is a Linux kernel bug that has been fixed in the version after `5.4`. Yet I don't have a proof, but my test showed me so.

---

### Question

I have been able to fix this app bug by calling `fclose` in the child process before it exits. But, I want to know what actually happen in this case. So my question is **How come forgetting `fclose` in child process affects the parent process?**

---

### Very simple code to reproduce the problem (3 files attached).

#### Note: The difference between test1.c and test2.c is only at `fclose` in the child process. test2.c does not call `fclose` in the child process.

#### File test.txt

```
123123123
123123123
123123123
123123123
123123123
123123123
```

#### File test1.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define TICK do { putchar('.'); fflush(stdout); } while(0)
int main() {
  char buff[1024] = {0};
  FILE *handle = fopen("test.txt", "r");

  uint32_t num_of_forks = 0;

  while (fgets(buff, 1024, handle) != NULL) {

    TICK;
    num_of_forks++;

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
      printf("Fork error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      continue;
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
      fclose(handle);
      exit(0);
    }
  }

  fclose(handle);
  putchar('\n');
  printf("Number of forks: %d\n", num_of_forks);
  wait(NULL);
}
```

#### File test2.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define TICK do { putchar('.'); fflush(stdout); } while(0)
int main() {
  char buff[1024] = {0};
  FILE *handle = fopen("test.txt", "r");

  uint32_t num_of_forks = 0;

  while (fgets(buff, 1024, handle) != NULL) {

    TICK;
    num_of_forks++;

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
      printf("Fork error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      continue;
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
      // fclose(handle);
      exit(0);
    }
  }

  fclose(handle);
  putchar('\n');
  printf("Number of forks: %d\n", num_of_forks);
  wait(NULL);
}
```

---

## Run the program

---

#### Run on Linux 5.4.0-58-generic (where the bug happens)

#### Look at test2 execution (bug), it leads to random number of fork syscall.

```
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ uname -r
5.4.0-58-generic
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.1) 2.31
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ cat test.txt
123123123
123123123
123123123
123123123
123123123
123123123
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ diff test1.c test2.c
27c27
<       fclose(handle);
---
>       // fclose(handle);
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ gcc test1.c -o test1 && gcc test2.c -o test2
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ ./test1
......
Number of forks: 6
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ ./test1
......
Number of forks: 6
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ ./test1
......
Number of forks: 6
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ ./test2
..................................................................................................................................................................................
Number of forks: 178
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ ./test2
............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Number of forks: 348
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ ./test2
...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Number of forks: 475
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ md5sum test1 test2
c32d03916b9b72546b966223837fd115  test1
f314d2135092362288a66f53b37ffa4d  test2
```

#### Run on Linux 5.10.0-051000-generic (the same code, no bug at all)

```
root@esteh:/tmp# uname -r
5.10.0-051000-generic
root@esteh:/tmp# gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

root@esteh:/tmp# ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.1) 2.31
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
root@esteh:/tmp# cat test.txt
123123123
123123123
123123123
123123123
123123123
123123123
root@esteh:/tmp# diff test1.c test2.c
27c27
<       fclose(handle);
---
>       // fclose(handle);
root@esteh:/tmp# gcc test1.c -o test1 && gcc test2.c -o test2
root@esteh:/tmp# ./test1
......
Number of forks: 6
root@esteh:/tmp# ./test1
......
Number of forks: 6
root@esteh:/tmp# ./test1
......
Number of forks: 6
root@esteh:/tmp# ./test2
......
Number of forks: 6
root@esteh:/tmp# ./test2
......
Number of forks: 6
root@esteh:/tmp# ./test2
......
Number of forks: 6
root@esteh:/tmp# md5sum test1 test2 # Make sure the files are identical with case 1
c32d03916b9b72546b966223837fd115  test1
f314d2135092362288a66f53b37ffa4d  test2
```

---

### Summary

- Forgetting `fclose` in the child process on `Linux 5.4.0-58-generic` causes the fork syscall in the parent process be strange.
- The bug does not seem to exist on `Linux 5.10.0-051000-generic`.

Comment: *File descriptor in child process should be independent against file descriptor in parent process* That's wrong. FDs across forks are different handles to the same FD after all, just like what you'd get with `dup(2)` or `dup2(2)`. Only closing (and duplicating) is independent, and when you read/write/`lseek(2)` from one FD, the other FD is also affected.

Comment: @iBug thanks for the correction. I want to clarify something to make sure I understand your comment in higher level (view from utils in `man 3 xxxx`). -- So, if I open a file with `fopen(3)`, **then** I call `fork(2)`, **then** I change the offset of `file handle which is created by the parent process` with `fseek(3)` from the child, **then** the offset of file handle in parent will change according to the `fseek(3)` call I do in child process.

Is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But keep in mind that process scheduling may make the result non-predictable, unless you implement some kind of "syncing".

Comment: Provide the glibc run-time version on each system.

Comment: @HadiBrais ok, I have just provided the glibc version on each system (post has been edited too). They both are identical version `ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.1) 2.31`. I checked it with `ldd --version` command.

Comment: I think your problem may be closely related to, if not the same as, the problem analyzed in [Why does forking my process cause the file to be read infinitely?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50112169/15168)

Comment: Thanks to @JonathanLeffler, I have been able to discover the real problem from your answer in that thread.

Comment: Thanks to @iBug too about the scheduling insight.

Comment: I suspected that you have a different version of glibc on the Linux 5.10 system in which the IO cleanup code is different. That's why I asked for the versions. But now we know that the "strange" behavior occurs on both systems, so it doesn't matter anymore. BTW, `ldd --version` gives you the linker version, not the glibc run-time version, which can be obtained by calling `gnu_get_libc_version()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Jonathan Leffler!

This problem is a duplicate of [Why does forking my process cause the file to be read infinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50110992/why-does-forking-my-process-cause-the-file-to-be-read-infinitely)

The missing knowledge, why does the bug not occur on `Linux 5.10.0-051000-generic` turned out that it is not related to the kernel.

---

It turned out that the parent process competes with the child processes (not related to kernel).

- Note: change the offset of file handle from **child process** will also change the offset in **parent process** if the **handle is created by the parent**.
- If there is no `fclose(3)` in the childs, the child processes will call `lseek(2)` as soon as they call `exit(3)`. This will cause the parent re-read the same offset, because the childs call `lseek(2)` with negative offset + `SEEK_CUR`.

(I don't know why it is necessary to call `lseek(2)` before exit, it might have been explained in @Jonathan Leffler's answer, I did not read the whole answer carefully).

- If the parent finishes to read the entire file before the childs call `lseek(2)`. Then there is no problem at all.

Also, as @iBug has mentioned *But keep in mind that process scheduling may make the result non-predictable, unless you implement some kind of "syncing".*

The parent process on `Linux 5.10.0-051000-generic` machine I used was just a **lucky process** that always won to read the entire file first before the childs call `lseek(2)`.

I tried to add more lines to the file (to be 150 lines), so the parent will mostly be slower than reading 6 lines, and the *undefined behavior* happens.

Test result: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ammarfaizi2/b72bd03fcc13779f96b8bbeef9253e66/raw/da1eff4ed5434aa51929e5c810d54de8ffe15548/test2_fix.txt

Comment: Why lseek happens: it's an unfortunate part of `fflush` that's needed in the general case of fflush, but probably *not* when exiting.  (Unless sticking to the letter of some spec mandates that, e.g. if `exit(3)` specifies `fflush(3)` by name.)  And yes, I found this at the bottom of Jonathan's excellent answer.  The workaround is to `fflush(stdin)` *before* forking, so exit finds that stdin buffer is empty (and thus the Unix fd position is in sync with the stdio read position, so lseek isn't needed).