# Save "perf stat" output per second to a file

Tags: linux, perf

I want to get perf output and analyse it. I used

```
while (true) {
      system("sudo perf kvm stat -e r10f4 -a sleep 1 2>&1 | sed '1,3d' | sed '2,$d' > 'system.log' 2>&1");
      sleep(0.5);
    }
```

The code above frequently uses perf, which is costly. Instead, I'm running perf stat like: `perf kvm stat -a -I 1000 > system.log 2>&1`.

This command will keep writting data to "system.log", but I only need the data in a second.

I'm wondering how to let the new data overwrites the older data every second.
Does anybody know if my thoughts are feasible? Or other ways which can solve my problem.

Comment: Is that C?  you know `sleep()` takes an unsigned int arg, right?  So that's `sleep(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You mean have perf keep overwriting, instead of appending, so you only have the final second?

One way would be to have your own program pipe `perf stat -I1000` into itself (e.g. via C stdio `popen` or with POSIX `pipe` / `dup2` / fork/exec).  Then you get to implement the logic that chooses where and how to write the lines to a file.  Instead of just writing them normally, you can lseek to the start of the output file before every write.  Or `pwrite` instead of `write` to always write at file-position 0.  You can append some spaces for padding out to a fixed width to make sure a longer line didn't leave some characters in the file that you're not overwriting.  (Or `ftruncate` the output file after writes with lines shorter than the previous line).

---

Or: redirect `perf stat -I 1000 >> file.log` with O_APPEND, and periodically truncate the length.

A file opened for append will automatically write at wherever the current end is, so you can leave `perf ... -I 1000` running and truncate the file every second or every 5 seconds or so.  So at most you have 5 lines to read through to get to the final one you actually want.  If using `system` to run it through a shell, use `>>`.  Or use `open(O_APPEND)`/`dup2` if using `fork` / `execve`.

To do the actual truncation, [`truncate()` by path, or `ftruncate()` by open fd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html), in a `sleep` loop.  Ideally you'd truncate right *before* a new line was about to be written, so most of the time there'd be a line.  But unless you make extra system calls like `fstat` or `inotify` you won't know when exactly to expect another one, although dead reckoning and assuming that sleep sleeps for the minimum time can work ok.

---

Or: redirect `perf stat -I 1000` (*without* append), and lseek its fd from the parent process, to create the same effect as piping through a process / thread that seeks before write.

[Why does forking my process cause the file to be read infinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50110992/why-does-forking-my-process-cause-the-file-to-be-read-infinitely/50112169#50112169) shows that parent/child processes with file descriptors that share the same open file description can influence each other's file position with `lseek`.

This only works if you do the redirect yourself with `open` / `dup2`, not if you leave it to a shell via `system`.  You need your own descriptor that refers to the same open file description

Not sure if you could play tricks like `lseek` on the same fd that a child process had open; in that case avoiding O_APPEND could let you set the write position to 0 without truncating, so the next write will overwrite the contents.  But that only works if you `open` / `dup2` / `fork`/`exec` and the fd in the parent has its file position tied to the fd in the child process.

#### Totally untested example

This might not actually compile even with the right headers, but hopefully illustrates the idea.

```
  // must *not* use O_APPEND, otherwise file position is ignored for write.
 int fd = open("system.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666);

 if ((pid = fork()) != 0){
     // parent
     while(1) {
         sleep(1);
         lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);    // reset the position at which perf will do its next write
     }
 } else {
     // child
     dup2(fd, 1);          // redirect stdout to the open file
      // TODO: look up best practices for fork/exec, and error checking
     execlp("sudo", "perf", "kvm", "stat", "-er10f4", "-a", "sleep", "1", NULL);
     perror("execlp sudo perf failed");
 }
```

Note the total lack of error checking of return values.  This is more like pseudocode, even though it's written in (hopefully) valid C syntax.

---

And BTW, you can reduce that pipeline to one `sed` command, just `sed -n 4p` to print line 4 but not other lines.  But `perf ... stat -I 1000` doesn't waste lines so there'd be no need to filter on line numbers that way.