# How to make this C function execute continuously?

Tags: c

I have a C program which takes an input from the command line, processes the input, generates a file and terminates.

For example myprogram.c lloks like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

//do something with the input
// and generate a file

exit(0);
}
```

I currently give an input as:
`echo -n abcd | myprogram.c`

What I want the program to do is instead of terminating after one input, it should keep on executing and wait for the next console input to generate the next file and so on.

Can someone guide me?

Comment: If you want something to happen repeatedly, use a loop. If you never want it to stop, use an infinite loop, ie, one with a condition which is always true. And you don't need to put `exit(0)` at the end of main, it's entirely redundant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you read scanf until EOF in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764014/how-do-you-read-scanf-until-eof-in-c)

Comment: @Useless, so basically wrapping the functionality within a `while(1)`? And how could I check whether the program is terminating or not and how can I give consecutive inputs to test this? As mentioned, currently my input is of the form `echo -n abcd | myprogram.c`

Comment: @rb-93 What would be the end condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool function(char *input)
{
    // do something with the input
    // and generate a file

    // example:
    if (strcmp(input, "exit") == 0)
        return true;

    printf("I did something with '%s'\n", input);
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: program_name <argument>.");
        return 1;
    }

    function(argv[1]);

    bool exit = false;
    while (!exit)
    {
        char input[32];
        scanf("%s", &input);
        exit = function(input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I not just wrap the entire functionality within the while loop instead of writing the same thing twice?

Comment: Yes, check my updated code

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is get `stdin` back to your control (terminal input) after a redirection. According to the [C-FAQ](http://c-faq.com/stdio/devtty.html) you can't do it in a portable way:

> There is no portable way of doing this. **Under Unix, you can open the special file /dev/tty**. Under MS-DOS, you can try opening the ``file'' CON, or use routines or BIOS calls such as getch which may go to the keyboard whether or not input is redirected.

But, if portability is not an issue, we can try a little work around (not optimal):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buf[1001], fname[10];
    FILE *fp;
    int i = 0;

    while(1) {
        if(fgets(buf, 1000, stdin)) {
            sprintf(fname, "mf%d", i++);

            if(!(fp = fopen(fname, "w"))) {
                perror("fopen");
                continue;
            }

            fprintf(fp, buf);
            fclose(fp);
        }

        if(!(stdin = fopen("/dev/tty", "r"))) {
            perror("stdin");
            exit(0);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The thing is, when you run the program, go to another terminal and get it's PID (`ps aux | grep myprog`). Say the PID is 12345 Then you do `ls -la /proc/12345/fd` and you'll see that the descriptor 0 is a pipe (done by the shell). So you need another stdin... and in Linux you can use `fopen("/dev/tty", "r")`, but again, not portable.